# How do I execute sudo commands on an ssh'ed machine?

Tags: bash, ssh

I wrote a short script that would ssh to a bunch of machines on a file called `config` that would iterate through the machines, ssh through them and create a new user on them. problem is - these commands require sudo privileges, and when I'm trying to execute `sudo` on them, I get a wrong password error, probably because sudo is not allowed over ssh? I'm not quite sure.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter remote admin username " adminuser
read -p "choose new username " newuser
read -p "choose new pass " newpass

while read -u10 HOST ; do ssh ${HOST} "uname -a" ;
sudo -S adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $newuser
sudo -S chpasswd <<<"$newuser:$newpass"
sudo -S chown $newuser /home/$newuser
#sudo -S  groupadd group
echo; echo "New user ${newuser} has been created on ${HOST}"

done 10< config.txt
```

It's worth to note I have set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `PermitRootLogin` to yes.

While we're at it, is there a way to minimize the amount of times i have to input my admin password? Right now I have to use it when I first ssh into the machine and when I execute a sudo command - so if I have 17 machines that's a minimum of 17 machines. I'd like to minimize that if possible.

Comment: Change your script to get the username and password from arguments or environment variables, so you can pass it to the script in a loop

Comment: Simplest might be to configure sudoers so that the user can run these commands without having to enter a password.

Comment: `sudo -S` expects to get the admin's password from stdin, so it should be in the `<<<` here-string.

Comment: i tried sudo -S adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $newuser <<< /tmp/usrpss but it also didnt work. i ofcourse created /tmp/usrpss with the password to test it, no luck

Comment: If you want to get it from a file, you have to use `<` not `<<<`.

Comment: i tried both <<< and <, they both failed: https://imgur.com/a/OT0V3he

Comment: Are you expecting that `ssh ${HOST} "uname -a"` will cause the rest of the commands in the loop to run on the remote host? This is not the case. The `sudo` commands currently run on your local machine.

Comment: The assumption that `sudo` is somehow disabled when you `ssh` is completely false anyway. This would be easy to confirm with a simple experiment. Try to reduce your problem to the simplest possible case for debugging; see also the guidance for including a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Please do not set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `PermitRootLogin` to `yes`. No reason to play with fire unless necessary.

On the remote machine, [use `visudo`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file) to define a group like  `admin` that never needs to enter a password in order to use `sudo`. Here are two lines from my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then add the user id to that Linux user group and the script will run as root without prompts for `sudo` passwords:

```sh
$ usermod -a -G admin my_user_name
```

Comment: this is how my sudoers file currently looks like: https://imgur.com/a/DhGqgIZ, but i still get an error prompting for a password. verified its in the admin group: https://imgur.com/a/VLtw8sS output on local machine: https://imgur.com/a/9UmaZkg

Comment: I did mention that your user id needs to be a member of the group. The instructions were extended to show you exactly how to do that also